# Python/socket/threading/tkinter: How to know the message sender?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I try to build an application that uses socket, threading and tkinter modules of Python. The application is about messaging of between a server and clients. If only one client is connecting to the server, the program runs well as i wish. However when the second client is connecting the server, the client names are mixed to each other. I wanted to design an application that the server could know the sender of any messages. When two clients connect to the server and then, one of them sends messages to the server, the sender of the messages can be seen only two times on the server screen then the sender of the messages will be the client that is the last connector.

Here are the codes:

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4, = buttons()


class Server:
    clients = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self):
        self.s.bind(("", 12345))
        self.s.listen(10)
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\nConnected.\n".format(now))
        self.condition()

    def accept(self):
        c, addr = self.s.accept()
        self.clients.append((c, addr))
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\n{} connected.\n".format(str(datetime.now())[:-7], addr))

    def receive(self):
        for i in self.clients:

            def f():
                data = str(i[0].recv(1024))[1:]
                now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
                if len(data) == 2:
                    pass
                else:
                    text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\n{}: {}\n".format(now, i[1], data))

            t1_2_1 = threading.Thread(target=f)
            t1_2_1.start()

    def condition(self):
        while True:
            t1_1 = threading.Thread(target=self.accept)
            t1_1.daemon = True
            t1_1.start()
            t1_1.join(1)
            t1_2 = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
            t1_2.daemon = True
            t1_2.start()
            t1_2.join(1)

    def send(self):
        respond = str(entry.get())
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        try:
            for i in self.clients:
                i.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nServer: {}\n".format(now, respond))
        except BrokenPipeError:
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nClient has been disconnected.\n".format(now))


s1 = Server()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=s1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=s1.send)
    t2.start()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1.configure(command=connect)
    b2.configure(command=send)
    b3.configure(command=clear)
    b4.configure(command=destroy)
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
    t0.run()
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Client")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4 = buttons()


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self):
        self.s.connect(("", 12345))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "Date: {}\nConnected.\n".format(now))
        self.receive()

    def receive(self):
        while True:
            data = str(self.s.recv(1024))[1:]
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            if len(data) == 2:
                pass
            else:
                text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nServer: {}\n".format(now, data))

    def send(self):
        respond = str(entry.get())
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        try:
            self.s.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\nClient: {}\n".format(now, respond))
        except BrokenPipeError:
            text.insert("insert", "\nDate: {}\Server has been disconnected. koptu.\n".format(now))
            self.s.close()


c1 = Client()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=c1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=c1.send)
    t2.start()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1.configure(command=connect)
    b2.configure(command=send)
    b3.configure(command=clear)
    b4.configure(command=destroy)
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
    t0.run()
```

Thanks in advance...

[Screenshot](https://i.hizliresim.com/jy7Xg9.jpg)

Comment: When you have multiple clients connected through the same interface (in this case a socket), they must identify themselves in the message content to the server. There are other mechanisms, pipes in particular, that implicitly provide client identity to the server. Bonus debug issue. In your client code, the `receive` method will block the thread forever because the `while` is always true and there is no break..

Comment: Thanks for your message. First, i don't know how to use pipes, i need to learn it. Second, I thought that there's no receive button on the application window therefore receiving a message should always be active. That's why the receive method has a while loop. But where should i write the break code? Can you give me suggestion?

Comment: And if i didn't misunderstand you, clients must send the information of who the senders are with their messages. So do you mean, according to the codes that i wrote, server has no chance to identify where the messages came from? Should the server codes be changed, in order to identify the senders in some way?

Comment: In the client codes, the while loop of the receive method does not block the other threads. As far as i can see, there's no blocked thread, when i send a message to the server, the message is sent immediately. Also the client can receive the server messages immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, here are the codes:

**server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Server")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Send", "Clear", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4, = buttons()


class Server:
    clients = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self):
        self.s.bind(("", 12346))
        self.s.listen(10)
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        text.insert("insert", "({}) : Connected.\n".format(now))
        self.condition()

    def accept(self):
        c, addr = self.s.accept()
        self.clients.append(c)
        data = c.recv(1024)
        text.insert("insert", "({}) : {} connected.\n".format(str(datetime.now())[:-7], str(data)[1:]))

    def receive(self):
        for i in self.clients:

            def f():
                data = str(i.recv(1024))[2:-1]
                now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
                if len(data) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    text.insert("insert", "({}) : {}\n".format(now, data))

            t1_2_1 = threading.Thread(target=f)
            t1_2_1.start()

    def condition(self):
        while True:
            t1_1 = threading.Thread(target=self.accept)
            t1_1.daemon = True
            t1_1.start()
            t1_1.join(1)
            t1_2 = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
            t1_2.daemon = True
            t1_2.start()
            t1_2.join(1)

    def send(self):
        respond = "Server: {}".format(str(entry.get()))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        try:
            for i in self.clients:
                i.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
            text.insert("insert", "({}) : {}\n".format(now, respond))
        except BrokenPipeError:
            text.insert("insert", "({}) : Client has been disconnected.\n".format(now))


s1 = Server()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=s1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=s1.send)
    t2.start()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


def destroy():
    root.destroy()
    exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1.configure(command=connect)
    b2.configure(command=send)
    b3.configure(command=clear)
    b4.configure(command=destroy)
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
    t0.run()
```

**client.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
import socket
import threading
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Client")

text = tk.Text(master=root)
text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
frame.pack()


def buttons():
    for i in "Connect", "Create A Nickname", "Send", "Clear", "Exit":
        b = tk.Button(master=frame, text=i)
        b.pack(side="left")
        yield b


b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 = buttons()


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.nickname = None

    def connect(self):
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        if self.nickname is not None:
            try:
                self.s.connect(("", 12346))
                text.insert("insert", "({}) : Connected.\n".format(now))
                self.s.sendall(bytes("{}".format(self.nickname).encode("utf-8")))
                self.receive()
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                text.insert("insert", "({}) : The server is not online.\n".format(now))
        else:
            text.insert("insert", "({}) : You must create a nickname.\n".format(now))

    def receive(self):
        while True:
            data = str(self.s.recv(1024))[2:-1]
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            if len(data) == 0:
                pass
            else:
                text.insert("insert", "({}) : {}\n".format(now, data))

    def do_nothing(self):
        pass

    def create_nickname(self):
        b2.configure(command=self.do_nothing)
        _frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
        _frame.pack()
        new_entry = tk.Entry(master=_frame)
        new_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
        new_button = tk.Button(master=_frame, text="Accept Your Nickname")
        new_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        def nickname_command():
            now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
            if new_entry.get() == "":
                text.insert("insert", "({}) : You must write a nickname.\n".format(now))
            else:
                self.nickname = new_entry.get()
                _frame.destroy()
                text.insert("insert", "({}) : Nickname has changed to: '{}'\n".format(now, self.nickname))
                b2.configure(command=c1.create_nickname)

        new_button.configure(command=nickname_command)

    def send(self):
        respond = "{}: {}".format(self.nickname, str(entry.get()))
        now = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
        entry.delete("0", "end")
        try:
            self.s.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))
            text.insert("insert", "({}) : {}\n".format(now, respond))
        except BrokenPipeError:
            text.insert("insert", "({}) : Server has been disconnected.\n".format(now))
            self.s.close()


c1 = Client()


def connect():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=c1.connect)
    t1.start()


def send():
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=c1.send)
    t2.start()


def clear():
    text.delete("1.0", "end")


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1.configure(command=connect)
    b2.configure(command=c1.create_nickname)
    b3.configure(command=send)
    b4.configure(command=clear)
    b5.configure(command=destroy)
    t0 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)
    t0.run()
```

Comment: Good improvements. The clients now identify themselves when they send messages. The server `connect` method will create threads until it crashes because the `while` loop will never break until an exception occurs.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i have not received an unexpected expection yet maybe because of the simplicity of the send/receive structure of the program. But after changing the codes to the current form, i decided that the screen of the server should be splitted in order to send the messages to a spesific client instead of all. Creating new windows according to a client is not difficult but sending messages to a spesific client is not easy as far as i can see. Because the `self.c.recv(1024)` refers all the clients. Maybe i should define new connections (c's)?

Comment: Sorry, in the last message, i made a mistake on this part: **Because the `self.c.recv(1024)` refers all the clients. Maybe i should define new connections (c's)?** I should write `i.sendall(bytes(respond.encode("utf-8")))`. This 'i' comes from the client list. And if server sends messages, all the clients will receive this message at the same time. This is the new problem. :) I will try to seperate the message sending process of the server side.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use this code but the infinite loop that keeps creating threads is filling up the memory with time. Is there a solution for that? Thnx